Use conditional formatting to fill x amount of cells before a date in a "gantt"
I have created a gantt chart in excel. Lefthand section for project details and righthande section for timeline as per the screenshot:

As you'll see you enter a project with start date, end date (cells formatted as date) and that populates the timeline. The formula used is =AND(G$5>=$C9,G$5<=$D9).
Row G holds the date in format DD/MM/YYYY with G5 being 01/01/2024
C9 is the start date.
D9 is the end date.
What I would now like is for the same amount of cells to be coloured that is in the days prep column.
So row 9 would be 14 cells coloured before the start date of 14/02/2024
Any help would be great.
Thanks
I've tired a few differnet formulas but honestly I'm just winging it and don't know what I'm doing.
I need a formula that goes "look at the start date, look at the days prep value, colour the same amount of cells that equal the prep value, and do it to the left of that start date."

perhaps use col() to get the column number of the cell with the date then conditional formatting for 14 cells prior.

Apply the two formulas in conditional formatting
=AND($C$2>=$A$2-G$1,($A$2-G$1)>0)  for the previous days
=AND(G$1<=$B$2,G$1>=$A$2)   for the days range
keep the order also.

